# How to use beanstalkc in Python to queue URLs and perform jobs

Tags: python, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I have a function named `spider` which takes `seed` as an argument. `seed` is the name of the URL I send to the spider function. Now my question is how do I use beanstalkc in Python to queue the URLs and perform the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/blob/master/TUTORIAL.mkd) you would need:

1. beanstalkd server is running.
2. Connect:

   ```
   import beanstalkc
   beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host='localhost', port=14711)
   ```
3. Add jobs using:

   ```
   beanstalk.put('seed url')
   ```
4. Get job via:

   ```
   job = beanstalk.reserve()
   spider(job.body)
   ```
5. Mark job as completed:

   ```
   job.delete()
   ```

Comment: job = beanstalk.reserve() spider(job.body)
can you please explain where am i sending the url(or seed) to spider 
because when i try printing job.body() it prints "True" not the url

Comment: It's an attribute so job.body not job.body(). Please follow the tutorial step by step first, that should give you a nice intro.